# Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ $f \rightarrow f'$

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a function $f$  which is $C^{\infty}$ and mapping  $f \rightarrow f'$ which is an endomorphism.

$\lambda$ is eigenvalue of a mapping   $\varphi$ and $u$ is its eigenvector if $\varphi(u) = \lambda u$

How can I apply it to my problem?

I know that $(a^x)' = \ln a \cdot a^x$, so $\ln a$ is the eigenvalue here.
And for constant functions we would have $0$ an the eigenvalue.

Could you help me with the rest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\varphi(f)=f'=\lambda f\iff f(x)=Ce^{\lambda x}$$
so any real $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $\varphi$ and the function $x\to e^{\lambda x}$ is an eigenvector.